# What happens to pending signals and signal masks on an exec?

Tags: unix, signals, exec

When I perform an exec() system call (any one of the 6 family of exec calls), what happens to pending signals and signal masks?

I understand, from the `man` page of `execve` that the signal dispositions are reset to their default. But it does not mention about signal dispositions and signal masks.

I would like to know what happens and any rationale behind why that happens.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is very well documented.

Signal behaviour is obviously reset to default if it was previously set to handler, as catching function code can't survive to `exec` by definition. If it was `SIG_DFL` or `SIG_IGN`, it remains so.

Process signal mask is inherited as documented.